# System.Lazy<T> and the System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode Enumeration

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, lazy-initialization

Using C#/.NET 4.0, a `Lazy<T>` object can be declared as follows.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
...
var factory = () => { return new object(); };
var lazy = new Lazy<object>(factory, LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);
```

Other options from the `LazyThreadSafetyMode` enumeration are `PublicationOnly` and `None`.

Why is there no `ExecutionOnly` option?

The behavior in this case would be that the factory method is called at most once by a single thread, even if multiple threads try to get `lazy.Value`.  Once the factory method was completed and the single result was cached, many threads would be able to access lazy.Value simultaneously (i.e., no thread safety after the initial factory method).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behavior you're describing is effectively `LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication`.  This allows multiple threads to access the `Value`,  but only a single thread to ever run the initialization method.

This enumeration is solely for determining how the creation occurs - you can always access `Value` from multiple threads.